# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, repository, entity

i have 2 table

### table01

NameID,Name (PK = NameID )

1,John
2,Rose

10,Mr.X

### 11,Mrs.X

### table02

CarID NameID CarName (PK = CarID , FK = NameID ) Relation

1,1,Benz

2,1,BMW

3,yYy

4,10,xXx

5,11,zZz

---

in my form i have 2 combobox

### combobox1 data = table01 data

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        //لود کردن کمبوباکس لایه
        comboBox1.DataSource = db.table01Repository.Get();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "NameID";
    }
}
```

combobox2 data = table02 data if NameID = NameID

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
    {
        using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
            comboBox2.DataSource = db.table02Repository.GetNameIDByFilter(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());

        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "CarName";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "CarID";
    }
}
```

now my problem 
if i change combox1 to 1 ( john )

my data incombobox2 =

Benz

BMW

xXx

zZz

this is because in SelectedIndexChanged ( count all 1 in table02 )

### how i must change my code to 1 = 1 ( just 1 ) not 1 = 1+ 0 or 1 = 1 + 1 + 0

my repository

```
public IEnumerable<table02> GetNameIDByFilter(string parameter)
{
    return db.table02.Where(g => g.NameID.ToString().Contains(parameter)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i find my mistake

IRepository

```
IEnumerable<table02> GetNameIDByFilter(string parameter);
```

Repository

```
public IEnumerable<table02> GetNameIDByFilter(string parameter)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(parameter, out int value))
        {
            return new List<table02>();
        }

        return db.table02.Where(g => g.NameID == value).ToList();
    }
```

Code in Form

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
            {
                comboBox2.DataSource = db.table02Repository.GetNameIDByFilter(selectedValue);

                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "CarName";
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "CarID";
            }
```